# Callback in rails doesn't seem to properly set file with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've got the following code in my controller:

```
def update
  binding.pry
  if @document.update_attributes(document)
    binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => "Document updated"}
      format.js { head 200 }
      format.json { head 200 }
    end
  end
end
```

When I inspect the params on the first binding, this is what I see:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "document"=>
  {"id"=>"2137",
   "image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff13d917248
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"loan_doc[image]\"; filename=\"banhammer.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
     @original_filename="banhammer.jpg",
     @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/33/5ylqh1755r14_9p3k470drgm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170628-15982-1u0xya8.jpg>>,
   "name"=>"mimetype",
   "notes"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Upload Document",
 "controller"=>"api/v1/documents",
 "action"=>"update"}
```

In `document.rb` I have a `before_save` callback that is as follows:

```
def convert_image
  return unless self.image_changed?
  return unless self.image.file.present?
  uploaded_image = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(:tempfile => File.open(self.image.file.file), :filename => self.image.file.filename)
  converted_image = ::DocumentUploader.upload_and_compress_document(uploaded_image, uploaded_image.original_filename)
  binding.pry
  self.image = converted_image
end
```

And also in that file, the carrierwave mounting code:

`mount_uploader :image, DocumentImageUploader`

If I do `@document.image.url` after the `update_attributes` call, I get `/image/9633/banhammer.pdf` in the URL

But if I go back in a rails console and make that same call on the same object, it returns this URL instead: `/image/9633/banhammer.jpg` -- which returns a 404 because the `.pdf` was uploaded, not the JPG.

I cannot figure out what's going on here and I'm at wit's end with carrierwave. How do I get it to stick with the original image?